# How to split column based on the min and max value of another column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to postgres trying to create a query but stuck halfway.

so here is the structure of my table:

[image: here is the image]

so I need to Return a list of rows from the events table that has the following columns:

1. The customer id
2. The time difference (in seconds) between their
   first and last events
3. The “types” of the first and last events
4. The location that the events originated from

I was able to create query but it does not solve point 3. and I am stuck.

```
select customer_id, location, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (max(tstamp) - min(tstamp))) AS difference  
from events 
GROUP BY customer_id ,location;
```

here is my partial solution output:

[partial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tOZK.png)

ANY help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`location` seems to be tied with the customer.  For the rest, I would suggest conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select customerid, location, min(tstamp), max(tstamp),
       extract(epoch from max(tstamp) - min(tstamp)),
       min(type) filter (where seqnum_asc = 1) as first_event,
       min(type) filter (where seqnum_desc = 1) as last_event
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by tstamp) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by tstamp desc) as seqnum_desc
      from events e
     ) e
group by customerid, location;
```